# Learning n-gram features using CNN model using keras for text data using python step by step

Tags: python-3.x, keras, nlp, conv-neural-network

I am trying to create features for my text corpus using convolution neural network (CNN). Say I want to learn 2-gram, 3-gram and 4-gram features as well ( Can be generalized to n-gram as well). I perform the following steps starting from my documents. I have taken a small document just to convey the idea.

```
documents = ["The Saudis are preparing a report that will acknowledge that", 
             "Saudi journalist Jamal Khashoggi's death was the result of an", 
             "interrogation that went wrong, one that was intended to lead", 
             "to his abduction from Turkey, according to two sources."]

Y =["A","B", "C","D"]
```

Step 1: All pre-processing step of documents

Step 2: Tokenization

Step 3: Create tf-idf features and represent it as DataFrame ( Document as row and tokens as features)

Step 4: Train CNN network to learn n-gram features

Step 5: Append the learned n-gram features along with previous features to the data frame.

#### I am stuck after Step 3

The code is given below:

```
def docs_preprocessor(docs):
tokenizer = RegexpTokenizer(r'\w+')
for idx in range(len(docs)):
    docs[idx]= " ".join(w.lower() for w in nltk.wordpunct_tokenize(docs[idx]) if w.lower() in words or not w.isalpha())
    docs[idx]= ' '.join(s for s in docs[idx].split() if not any(c.isdigit() for c in s))
    docs[idx] = tokenizer.tokenize(docs[idx])  # Split into words.
    
    

# Remove numbers, but not words that contain numbers.
docs = [[token for token in doc if not token.isdigit()] for doc in docs]

# Remove words that are only one character.
docs = [[token for token in doc if len(token) > 3] for doc in docs]

# Lemmatize all words in documents.
lemmatizer = WordNetLemmatizer()
docs = [[lemmatizer.lemmatize(token) for token in doc] for doc in docs]
docs=[ " ".join(doc)  for doc in docs]

return docs
```

Perform function on our document.

docs = docs_preprocessor(docs)

Simple pre processing.

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer
vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer()
doc_vec = vectorizer.fit_transform(df.text) # scipy.sparse.csr.csr_matrix

# Now convert to data frame:
df2 = pd.DataFrame(doc_vec.toarray(),columns=vectorizer.get_feature_names())
```

`After this step, I am stuck. How should I train CNN network using Keras to learn the n-gram features and add the features in the dataframe along with previous features. It would be helpful if someone can run on small datasets mentioned above.`

`Python 3.6`